# Outlook Cached mode is not updating user's email changes back to the server

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, exchange-2010

I have a user having problems with Outlook Cached mode. It seems that changes she makes to her inbox are not being made server side.

For example, if an email is deleted or moved to a different folder then according to the server that email is still in the inbox.

This first came to light when a new PC was provisioned for this employee and they logged into Outlook. The inbox had literally thousands of emails in, all of which had been handled and cleared away previously.

New messages are arriving without any problems, although occasionally we have to click the "Update This Folder" button within Outlook. This aspect seems more of a problem on the new Outlook 2010 install than it was under Outlook 2003 on the old machine.

Other PC's in the office seem to be fine. I'm checking this by looking at the Synchronization tab under the Inbox properties and checking the "Server folder contains" and "Offline folder contains" figures match.

I'd welcome suggestions of how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this user have another device connected to her inbox? (ie. blackberry or android device). It might be that the Blackberry, or other device, is interfering with the mailbox.

Also, another tool/check I often use is OWA/OWAP to connect to the Exchange server, if you are using Exchange. See if the user can login and see all the email, move an email to another folder then check in Outlook.

If the email has been moved but Outlook does not see it, I woudl move her mailbox to another database. I have found that sometimes a move can help solve these weird anomalies. I have foudn that even just login into the OWA/OWAP webmail fixed some issues.

Let me know!

MortisO